# ubuntu 14.04 .1 package installation error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openstack

I am trying to run the following command:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/testing`

but it is giving me the following error:

`Cannot add PPA : 'ppa:cloud-installer/testing'  Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

any solutions?

Comment: thank you sir for editing the question but can you suggest me any answer

Answer (score 0):

See these [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct), at AskUbuntu.

You will see:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

And, if it does not work:

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/testing
```

Or, as stated [here, also in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564780/openstack-installation-on-ubuntu-non-graphical-server-edition-14-04-1):

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openstack-ubuntu-testing/kilo
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates is not working

Comment: sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa here after the slash i have to put the testing

Comment: please confirm the i have to run this command sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/testing

Comment: sir i am currently resetting my virtual machine i will inform the result with in 15 mins since i have to update my ubuntu first and then i will run your provided command